# Direct Link through Juniper Portal

Tags: juniper

We have a Juniper portal in front of our web applications. When we navigate to our primary URL (e.g., https://apps.ourdomain.com), everything routes properly to our primary web site. However, if we try to navigate directly to an application URL (e.g., https://apps.ourdomain.com/ourapplication/page.aspx?param1=x&param2=y), we are still routed to the primary web site, rather than to the secondary web application.

Is it possible for Juniper to allow a link directly to an internal application, without having to encode the URL (e.g., https://apps.ourdomain.com/ourapplication/,DanaInfo=.adfx098lkjlkj,SSL+page.aspx?param1=x&param2=y) first?

Comment: Juniper as in Juniper SSL VPN appliance?

Comment: We're using the MAG Series Junos Pulse Gateway.

Comment: If I understand the question right, you just want the URL to not be rewritten, but instead just proxy it straight through?  I know there's a way in the regular SA appliances, but haven't messed with the MAG.  But if that's what you are wanting, I'm sure I can find a KB article about how to do it.

Comment: I don't mind if it's rewritten... I just want the original link to work straight through the gateway. On its way to getting my content, it's okay if it's rewritten. It's just that now, the direct link won't get me where I'd like to go.

Yes, I would appreciate any content you can find on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this KB article: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/sa8.0/topics/task/operational/secure-access-web-rewrite-passthrough-proxy-policy.html

I'd copy/paste the whole thing, but markdown will mess it all up.

But in short:

> Passthrough proxy resource policies specify Web applications for which
>   the Secure Access Service performs minimal intermediation. To create a
>   passthrough proxy resource policy, you need to specify two things:
>
> - Which Web application to intermediate with the passthrough proxy
> - How the Secure Access Service listens for client requests to the application server